# swift 5 ios : how do I get data out of a session.dataTask completion handler

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code, its not complete its just for example.

```swift
    func getUserData() {
        var user: UserData // creates an empty userdata object
        // setup for session.dataTask below, skipping since this isn’t my question
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            …
            // process data here
            let json = JSONSERializable.jsonobject…
            // How can I get the json variable out into the function?
            // Because I can do something like:
            let id = json[“id”] as? String ?? “”
            let name = json[“name”] as? String ?? “”
            // And I would want to do something like:
            userdata.id = id
            userData.name = name
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

but the above userdata. Statements are errors,  I can’t seem to wrap my mind around this concept.

I have an app that makes a lot of requests to a restful api and I get json data payloads to use in the app.  so I have a lot of these type of data calls, and want to create a class of methods to access the various aspects of the remote db.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all `user` is not equal to `userdata`. Create the object as optional on the top level of the class to be able to use it in the entire class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is working for me:

```
    func loadJson(fromURLString urlString: String,
                      completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                completion(.success(data))
            }
        }
        urlSession.resume()
    }
}
```

And use:

```
 loadJson(fromURLString: urlString) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let data):
        // Parse your Json: I call a function Parse that does it
        //if let decodedJson = GetJson.parse(jsonData: data) {
            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Use your decodedJson
                //print(decodedJson.id)
                //print(decodedJson.name)
            //}
                
       }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)         
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use the `DispatchQueue.main.async` if you want to use the data in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user object conforms to Codable for example:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    
        case id = "user_id" //If the parameters of your json object you receive are named differently than the variable name above
        case name
    }
}
```

Then in your `getUserData()` function you can do the following:

```
func getUserData(_ completion: @escaping(User?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "example.com")!

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)


    session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
    
        guard let data = data else {
        //THERE IS NO DATA RETURNED, Might want to handle this case
            return
        }
    
        do {
            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) //Creates a User Object if your JSON data matches the structure of your class
            completion(user, nil)
        } catch (let decodingError) {
            completion(nil, decodingError)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Then it terms of actual usage you could do:

```
func loadDataAndUpdateUI() {
    getUserData { (user, error) in
        if let user = user {
            userIdLabel.text = user.id
        } else if let error = error {
            //Handle or show this error somehow
        }
    }
}
```